# List all internet connections

Tags: internet, network-monitoring

I'd like to know all the connections my system is making to the internet. I tried `netstat` but that shows a lot of connections - all of which aren't applicable I think. Can it be displayed like `top` does for processes ?

I'm a little security conscious and would like to know all the incoming and outgoing connections happening on my system.

Comment: Usually all you need is `sudo ss -tulpn`. For Apache, you might want to configure `mod_status`

Answer (score 41):

### Using `netstat`

**Warning**: Netstat [is considered deprecated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/261224/209677).

`netstat` by itself monitors all major protocols including TCP and UDP on every port.

If you want to display TCP and UDP connections:

```
netstat -t -u
```

If you want to display that continuously:

```
netstat -t -u -c
```

### Similar to `top`

1. [**nethogs**](http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/) - shows a list of the **top processes** that use bandwidth
2. [**jnettop**](http://jnettop.kubs.info/wiki/) - shows list of top connections
3. [**iftop**](http://www.ex-parrot.com/%7Epdw/iftop/) - shows list of top connections *with bandwidth bars*

### GUI Interface (just in case):

1. [**Ntop**](http://www.ntop.org/products/traffic-analysis/ntop/)
2. [**Netactview**](http://netactview.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: typo: nethlogs -> nethogs,  jnettot->jnettop

Answer (score 2):

### Using `ss`

You may try `ss` as well, **it's more advanced than `netstat`**.

- **`ss --tcp -all`**

  List all TCP connections (including those with non-established state, e.g. `SYN-SENT`, `LISTEN`, and `TIME-WAIT`). Read more about TCP states transition in [RFC793](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc793).

  ```
  State                    Recv-Q               Send-Q                             Local Address:Port                                 Peer Address:Port     
  LISTEN                   0                    4096                                   127.0.0.1:5672                                      0.0.0.0:*    
  ESTAB                    0                    0                                    192.168.1.4:57310                               35.157.63.229:443  
  ESTAB                    0                    0                                      127.0.0.1:43764                                   127.0.0.1:8080 
  CLOSE-WAIT               1                    0                                    192.168.1.4:34554                              142.250.186.33:443  
  CLOSE-WAIT               1                    0                                    192.168.1.4:34564                              142.250.186.33:443
  ```
- **`ss --tcp --all --processes`**

  Include information about the owner process of the connections (e.g., *process name* and *PID*)
- **`ss state established '( dport = :ssh or sport = :ssh )'`**

  Display all established SSH connections.
- **`ss --options state fin-wait-1 '( sport = :https )' dst 193.233.7/24`**

  List all the TCP sockets in state `FIN-WAIT-1` for network 193.233.7/24 and look at their timers with `--options`, which shows timer information.

Comment: This is the correct answer. netstat is considered deprecated on ubuntu https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278474/why-is-netstat-deprecated https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258711/alternative-to-netstat-s