# System Monitor -Network History shows activity when internet not being used

Tags: networking, wireless

I noticed that the system monitor's network history shows activity when I am connected to the wifi, even when I am not using my browser. Is there a way I could see which applications are using the network and kill them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [List all internet connections](http://askubuntu.com/questions/333921/list-all-internet-connections)

Answer (score -1):

open a terminal and type  . `netstat -a`
yo can save the command output by using `netstat -a > /home/user/folder/file.txt`

Comment: This doesn't not  cover the complete goal of OP!

Comment: -1 `-a` isn't enough to make `netstat` show the process responsible for the connection.